# Center <a> element in navbar header parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello stackoverflow people, I need help with centering my `Website Title`, here is the print screen of website:
[image]

As you can see `Website title` is in the left of the navbar here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!--Mobilus buttonas-->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website title</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left main_nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">                     
                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>               
                <li><a href="#contact">Contacts</a></li>                           
            </ul>          
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'am using bootstrap so there is no point posting css, so I will give you jsfiddle so it could be simplier: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18964/ . So i repeat, I don't know how to make `Website Title` in the center of website?

Comment: Why don't you simply move the anchor with "Website title" between the two ul's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar-brand { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: Note that transform [isn't supported by IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 0):

Build something like col5-col2-col5. You maybe have to adjust this for other resolutions. Centering stuff without flexbox is always a pain.
Like this:

```
    <header id="header">
    <!--Meniu laukas-->
    <div class="menu_area">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left main_nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website title</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left main_nav pull-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18972/

Answer (score 0):

add the following class in your css
 you may adjust this value for various media queries and add the class to the container check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18975/

```
.center-container{width:705px;}
```